# Flask – multiple subdomains with shared functionality

Tags: python, flask, subdomain, plotly-dash

I have been scouring the web to help me find the best way to do this and haven't found a proper answer.

I want to create a single web app with flask that contains multiple dashboard pages. The app needs to run on a different subdomain for every user–the user being a different business eg. `client1.myapp.com`. The functionality will be largely shared across the different clients and thus subdomains. However, I want to define a config file that will look something like this:

```
client1 = {"show_graph1":True, "show_graph2":False}
client2 = {"show_graph1":False, "show_graph2":True}
```

So the app would be hosted on a single aws elastic beanstalk instance and serve all these subdomains. The flow would be:

1. Client1 goes on unique url `client1.myapp.com`
2. Client1 logs in to myapp
3. Myapp recognises that it is on subdomain for client1, fetches the configuration from the config file and configures the dashboard pages accordingly.

I have looked into flask blueprints and from what I've understood this would be the best way to set this up, but I am not clear on how I would dynamically fetch and implement the configuration nor on how will flask simultaneously serve all subdomains at once.

What would be the best application structure to setup this use case with flask?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your flask app is listening for all connections, you can point as many domains to it as you like. Then in your dashboard views, or globally if you prefer, you can get your configuration based on what domain the app was requested through.

For example:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request_func():
    domain = request.host
    g.client_config = get_client_config(domain)
```